# Is it possible to show a relationship (e.g. line or ray) between an inner and outer pie chart in Apache Echarts?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

Using Apache Echarts, I have a nested pie chart (inner chart with radius [0,40%] and outer with radius [%60,%75]). The inner pie chart is a more detailed breakdown of space used by a particular database. The outer chart shows the higher level picture of breakdown of available storage space from the OS perspective. The orange section labeled "This DB" shows the amount of total storage space consumed by this database - in other words, it represents the total impact of the inner pie as a whole.

I would like to visually represent this relationship to make it easier to interpret by drawing a line or arrow or some other indication of relationship between the inner pie chart and the section on the outer chart where it is re-represented (here, in orange). I've drawn in the red arrow using a painting tool after taking a screen capture. How do I get something like that arrow programmatically either in ECharts or, if not possible, using javascript and something standard for drawing the arrow?

Side note: please ignore the overlapping labels on the inner pie chart. That's due to a bug in Echarts I haven't yet figured out, but isn't what I'm asking about now.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... so ECharts has a series type "lines" (not the same as "line") which can draw lines (with symbols) on a graph using coordinateSystem: "cartesian2d" and a set of start/end x/y values for data.coords.

```
     {
      type: 'lines',
      name: "arrow",
      data: [{ coords: additionalLineData }],
      symbol: ["none","arrow"],
      symbolSize: 40,
      coordinateSystem: 'cartesian2d',
      lineStyle: {
        width: 5,
        color: "#777777",
        opacity: 1
      }
```

I then had to calculate where on the graph the arrow should be placed, and I managed that with some trigonometry:

```
   // get geometry of chart div
   const rect = currChartObj.getDom().getBoundingClientRect()

   // compute the size of our X-axis so that a unit of X and a unit of Y have the same pixel length (perfect square grid)
   xAxisMax = 100 * (rect.width / rect.height)

   // what percent of the outer pie does this database represent?
   const thisDbPctOfStorage = parseInt(currentStats[node.synonyms["OS_FILE_USED_SPACE_BYTES"]]) / parseInt(currentStats[node.synonyms["STORAGE_BYTES_ALLOCATED"]])

   // what is the degrees on a 360 degree circle of the midpoint of this database segment, given that the top of the circle starts at 90 degrees and diminishes clockwise in the opposite direction of our data values?
   const thisDBOuterShiftDeg=(90-(thisDbPctOfStorage * 360 * 0.5))

   // if midpoint goes negative, wrap around the 360 degree
   const thisDBOuterShiftDegrees= thisDBOuterShiftDeg < 0 ? 360 + thisDBOuterShiftDeg : thisDBOuterShiftDeg

   // convert to radians ( degrees * (pi/180) )
   const thisDbOuterPieRadians = thisDBOuterShiftDegrees * (3.1415926 / 180)

   // compute absolute center of pie charts
   const xMidPoint = Math.floor(xAxisMax / 2)
   const yMidPoint = Math.floor(yAxisMax / 2)

   // compute distance (length of ray) from absolute center to the middle of the outer pie chart
   const distanceToOutsideCenter = ((yAxisMax/2)-((yAxisMax-outsideInnerRadius)/2)) + ((outsideOuterRadius - outsideInnerRadius)/4)

   // compute distance (length of ray) from the absolute center to the outer edge of our inner pie chart
   const distanceToInsideOuterEdge = (yAxisMax/2)-((yAxisMax-insideRadius)/2)

   // using deltaX = sin(angle in rad) and deltaY = cos(angle in rad), find the new X, Y coordinates for the start and end of our arrow so it starts on the outer edge of the inner pie and ends in the
   // middle of the outer pie chart centered in the segment representing this database. This will be fed into the PieChart component as data for the lines series.
   innerToThisDbOuterLineData = [
                                 [xMidPoint + (distanceToInsideOuterEdge * Math.cos(thisDbOuterPieRadians)),yMidPoint + (distanceToInsideOuterEdge * Math.sin(thisDbOuterPieRadians))], // start
                                 [xMidPoint + (distanceToOutsideCenter * Math.cos(thisDbOuterPieRadians)),yMidPoint + (distanceToOutsideCenter * Math.sin(thisDbOuterPieRadians))] // end
                                ]
```

It also required that I place a "grid" option covering 100% of the chart div and x/y axes with the correct maximum values so my cartesian coordinates would line up with the pie chart:

```
grid: {
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  containLabel: false
},
xAxis: {show: false, min: 0, max: xAxisMax},
yAxis: {show: false, min: 0, max: yAxisMax},
```

Result:

[image]